# Core-Data: Parent context changes not being merged into child context

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My situation is: I have a multi-threaded app with core-data database, managing multiple contexts. In my context Hieratchy I have a Root Saving Context, and child contexts where I fetch data and make/save changes.

- Context A -> Root parent context
- Context B -> Child context of A
- Context C -> Child context of A

Context B is used to fetch data and be displayed in a View Controller's view.

Context C is used to save changes in a background thread.

The problem is that when I make changes in context C, save context C and A, the changes are not propagated, or merged, into context B. The changes are correctly persisted in context A and C, but not in B.

I thought that the default behaviour would be that the changes in a parent context A would be propagated into it's child context B, but it's not happening. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are working on an iOS 10 project you can try setting the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` property on *Context B* to `true`.

For older projects you have to merge changes yourself:

- Observe the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification. Make sure to use *Context C* as the object when subscribing. Otherwise you will receive notifications from any context that has been saved, not just from *Context C*.
- Use `NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave:)` to update *Context B*. The Objective-C selector is `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`

Comment: Just found out about `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`, and that the default is `NO`. solved my problem:) . By the way, the solution for iOS previous than 10 resulted useful!

Comment: NB! Note that "automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent" does not merge changes immediately after calling save on the parent context. There is a slight delay. If you need the changes merged immediately, also use the "[context refreshObject:mergeChanges]" method.